# Handle private mutations with Apollo federation

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

In a micro-service architecture, I do have GraphQL mutations that are deemed to be used by the end-user, and some more that are only internal.

I am planning to move to Apollo Federation. Is there a built-in way to declare a mutation as unexpected, so that it is not accessible to the end-user but can be called by an internal service directly?

I am not sure what the best design for this would be ; I would not want ending up in a situation for which I have to run two different servers for micro services: a public and a private one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No, there is not a built-in or conventional way to declare parts of your schema as "private." You could devise your own `@private` [schema directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/), which could wrap resolvers with an authentication check that requires a service API key rather than a user access token. These mutations would still be visible on in your schema — that is, they will likely appear in any automatically generated API documentation — but they would be effectively unusable by regular users. In [this Apollo Server issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2812), an Apollo dev mentions plans to provide a built-in `@internal` directive for this purpose, but it doesn't seem to be available yet.